# I want to clear the css / html cache of Pentaho's Tomcat server

Tags: css, tomcat, pentaho

I am making changes to the css theme files of Pentaho (Community Edition, Version 7), but although the files are updated on the server, they do not seem to deploy up to what the Tomcat server sends.

Any hints at some parameters which should be changed? some places which should be cleared after stopping the Tomcat server and before restarting it?

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? I had a problem with Chrome, it caches some data aggressively and I needed to clear browsing data for changes to appear.

Comment: Checked with FF (my preferred), Chrome as well as Edge.
no visivble change

Comment: Have you tried calling http://localhost:8080/pentaho/plugin/pentaho-cdf-dd/api/renderer/refresh ? You need to change localhost to appropriate address if you are not running it locally.